# Backbone, JST, EJS: Blank values in templates

Tags: backbone.js, ejs, jst

I have a JST-->EJS backbone template for a 'projects' form. Ideally, I'd like to use the same template for both creating and editing models.

At the moment, I have something such as this in the template:

```
<input type='text' name='demo_field' value='<%= demo_field %>' />
```

That works fine so long as demo_field has a value, but if it doesn't, the whole form fails with an uncaught referenceError.

So, what's the most elegant way to assure variable fields return blank, instead of fail, in Backbone...or JST...or EJS?

Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably make a helper, since javascript doesn't have any nice way of doing something like
`field if field?` in CoffeeScript.

Throw something like this into a helper function:

```
function printIfExists(field) {
  return (typeof field !== "undefined" && field !== null) ? field : '';
}
```

and call it in your templates.  Easy as pie!

You might also want to use the alternate `function` declaration:

```
var printIfExists = function(field){...}
```

I've been using coffeescript so long I can't recall why... scoping issues with the former example, probably.

Comment: Hi wulftone - thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, I can't seem to pass the field into the helper. It throws the 'uncaught referenceerror' when passing the field into the helper if it isn't present. Eg: <%= printIfExists(my_field) %> throws reference error if my_field is undefined, before reaching the printIfExists function

Comment: If you're not stuck on EJS (I noticed in your other post that you're using coffescript elsewhere), I'd recommend using ECO instead, so you can get your coffeescript in your JSTs.. then you can do `field if field?`

Comment: honestly, i found it most useful in my own projects to pass the entire backbone object into the jst, so I call my fields with `@myModel.get 'myfield'` and backbone simply returns `null` if that field doesn't exist